# Summarizing a small numerical dataframe using FLAN T5

Tags: dataframe, openai-api, transformer-model, huggingface, large-language-model

I am trying to fine tune the Flan T5 model to summarize a pandas dataframe, which mostly contain numerical values and a date column. I expect it to understand the small dataset along with the dates. How should I feed the data to the model so that it best understands the data?

I am using the following prompt which I cannot change: What do you understand by this data? Respond within 2 Lines.

I am building a pipeline to do prompt tuning later using some labelled data, but the above is the first step.

I am a beginner to LLMs and have tried loading data in json format but it is not showing satisfactory results

Comment: fine tuning looks flan t5 looks like [this](https://www.philschmid.de/fine-tune-flan-t5) , how much data did you fine tuned it on?